# Hibernate allocationSize use in custom sequence generator

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

We are using a SequenceGenerator which is using sequence of our PostgreSQL DB. We know that by default allocationSize() is 50.

Problem is we are moving to custom sequence generator which extends SequenceGenerator class and overridden the function generate(). But some how this is not working and this is contacting DB every time and not keeping buffer on server after multiplying the current sequence by allocationSize().

This is current code of customer sequence generator:

```
    public class UseExistingOrGenerateIdGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
            throws HibernateException {
        Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object)
                .getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
        return id != null ? id : (super.generate(session, object));
    }

}
```

In some other class defined the getter:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PrimaryID", nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)

    @GenericGenerator(name = "primaryIdSeq",
            strategy = "com.data.generator.sequence.UseExistingOrGenerateIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "Primary_id_SEQUENCE")
            })
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "primaryIdSeq")
    public BigDecimal getReturnId() {
        return this.returnId;
    }
```